# How to extract filename from a string in c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I extract the filenames (excel spreadsheets .xls) from below sample string? Note: string here can be anything and only known thing i nth string is the extension (.xls) & filename is enclosed in single quotes.

```
string text = "...
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:parent.ShowSheet('abc test 1.xls')">abc</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:parent.ShowSheet('xyz test 2.xls')">XYZ</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>...";
```

Only thing I know here is the extension (.xls). By using combination of string.Substring() & string.IndexOf I can get the text after ".xls" but i need to get the text before ".xls" upto the filename only. How can I get the IndexOf the character ' (single quote) that comes just before ".xls"?

Comment: How can I find the IndexOf ' (single quote) that comes just before ".xls" here in this string?

Comment: I'd do a google search for an appropriate "html parser", and use that tool to get values from your html.

Comment: given file names now can have spaces in that whole string could be a filename

Comment: Well, I do not want to user HTML parser here as the string may be anything here. The suggested string is just an example. Only thing I know here is the string contains ".xls"  and the filename is enclosed with the single quotes.

Comment: @giparekh As others have already commented that "html scraping" is error prone, but to answer your question you can use `text.LastIndexOf('\'', indexOfXls)` to find the first single quote to the left of `indexOfXls`.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis yes, LastIndexOf works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression of `'[^']*'` will match:

- Full match    55-71   `'abc test 1.xls'`
- Full match    127-143 `'xyz test 2.xls'`

C# Code to do this is:

```
    string text = @"...
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href=""javascript:parent.ShowSheet('abc test 1.xls')"">abc</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href=""javascript:parent.ShowSheet('xyz test 2.xls')"">XYZ</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>...";

    var matches = Regex.Matches(text, "'[^']*'");

    foreach(var match in matches)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(match);
    }
```

Here's a fiddle of it working - https://dotnetfiddle.net/JKzY6J

Comment: As I mentioned, the string is here is just a part of the main string (full HTML page) only and the whole string may contains many other texts enclosed by single quotes. So in this case this solution might not work.

Comment: If you want to make it more strict just change the regex to match `('*.xls')`

Comment: You can always just extend the regex to detect the full `javascript:parent\.ShowSheet\('([^']+\.xls)'\)`. A capture group in the regex will allow you to cut out the part you need.

Answer (score 0):

> string here can be anything and only known thing in the string is the
>   extension (.xls) & filename is enclosed in single quotes

Split string by `'` and take only vlaues wich ends with `.xls`

```
var fileNames = raw.Split('\'')
                   .Where(value => value.EndsWith(".xls"))
                   .ToList();
```

But you can break approach above if string contains `.xls'` without previous `'` character.

```
"<a href=""Sheet('abc test 1.xls')"">abc.xml'</a><a href=""Sheet('xyz test 2.xls')""></a>"
                                        -----
```